# Javascript array with callback function

Tags: javascript

I tried to have better understanding of JavaScript. Here is a piece of code that I read from [JavaScript function closures](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/let.html).

```
var funcs = [];
// create a bunch of functions
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   funcs.push(function() {
    console.log(i);
   })
}
// call them
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  funcs[j]();
}
```

The array `funcs` has a push callback function. I don't why in the `J` loop, `funcs[j]()` will call this function to print the `i` in the console.

I have tried to understand this sequencey by adding some console messages:

```
var funcs = [];
console.log("start");
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  console.log("i:" + i);
  funcs.push(function(){
    console.log(i);
  })
}

console.log("J loop");
for (var j=0; j<3; j++) {
  console.log("j:" + j);
  funcs[j]();
}
```

As expected, there is `3` for all three functions.

My question is: How does `funcs[j]()` calls the `funcs.push(...)` function?
I understant the `funcs[j]` is reference the `j` element of the `funcs` array. But why having parentheses `()` will call the `push(...)` function?

Comment: It doesn't call the `.push()` function; it calls the function that was *passed* to `.push()`, the little function with `console.log(i);` inside.

Comment: @Pointy can you explain a little bit more? That's what I am confused about. Why does it call the function that was passed to `.push()`? It is a syntax or something else?

Comment: .push add element at the end of the array. In first loop you pushed a function to the array. In second loop , you are  invoking the function with ()  [] indicating index.

Comment: Possibly separately from what confusing you, the code above also has the issue that the value of `i` may surprise you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`function() {console.log(i);}` is an expression which evaluates to a value that is function that logs `i`.

`funcs.push` is a function that adds a value to an array.

Putting `()` after a function will call that function.

`funcs.push(some_value)` calls the `push` function and passes `some_value` as the value to put in the array.

`funcs.push(function() {console.log(i);})` adds the function to the array.

The value of `funcs[0]` becomes that function.

Putting `()` after a function will call that function.

`funcs[0]()` calls the function that is the first value in the array.

Comment: Thank you for the step by step explanation!  It's very helpful!

Comment: So putting `()` after a function will always invoke whatever function in the `push()`?

Comment: Putting `()` after a function will invoke that function. Putting it after something which represents the function which was pushed into the array will invoke that function.

Answer (score -1):

First, the 'i' variable are global, and ending the loop, i=3
Then, the functions inside funcs, use the variable "i", then, all functions print "3" in console.

Maybe you wanted to do this:

```
var funcs = [];
console.log("start");
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  console.log("i:" + i);
  funcs.push(function(i){
    console.log(i);
  })
}

console.log("J loop");
for (var j=0; j<3; j++) {
  console.log("j:" + j);
  funcs[j](j);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't have a problem to understand why it prints `3` three times. I just have a problem about why `()` will invoke the `console.log(i)` function. And @Quentin did a great job to explain it.